# Maven Build - aggregation plus parent

Tags: maven, parent-pom, aggregator

`pom.xml (Aggregator - setup submodules A,B,C)<br/>
    | project-A / pom.xml
    | project-B / pom.xml (Set Project A as Parent)
    | project-C / pom.xml (Set Project A as Parent)`

When I trigger install on root pom.xml, it throws an exception that is saying Non-resolvable parent POM failre to find project A.....

Understood we can manually build A first then sovle it. Howeverm

Does anyone know how to fix the pom structure so that I can call the root pom only, which can build all projects in one go?

Comment: Could you add your parent's pom there?

Comment: Why not correctly create a multi module build and let maven decide the build order ?

Comment: @Luc Do you mean put parent pom to root?. it will not be working.

Comment: @khmarbaise Aggregator pom already done this job.